# matplotlib legend that is ordered by the last Y values, and have lines from the last plot point to the legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm probably not describing this well in the title, but can someone post an example of how to do a legend as in the these graphs:

[image]

Requirements:

1. Legend text is sorted by the last values of the plot y-datas.
2. There is a line from the last plot point to the legend label with the correct line style, color, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with using `annotate` rather than try to futz with `legend`, it provides a great deal of control over placement and properties.  Here's a minimum example which together with the documentation for `annotate` should push you in the right direction, it results in this plot:
[image]

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make example data
x = np.linspace(0,2.0,50)
y1 = x**0.5
y2 = x**1.5
y3 = x**0.2

# Plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,facecolor='white')
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8) # Make room for annotations
p1, = ax.plot(x, y1)
p2, = ax.plot(x, y2, '--')
p3, = ax.plot(x, y3, '-.')
pp = [p1, p2, p3]

# Get sort indices from last ydata
yp = np.array([y1[-1], y2[-1], y3[-1]])
s = np.argsort(yp)

# Create annotation locations (I've used axes fraction coordinates)
# and am assuming they are evenly spaced
a_posx = np.tile([1.1], 3)
a_posy = np.linspace(0,1,3)

# Map plot linestyles to terminology expected by an annotation FancyArrowPatch
ls = [p.get_linestyle() for p in pp]
lsmap = {'-':'solid', '--':'dashed', ':':'dotted', '-.':'dashdot'}
als = map(lsmap.get, ls)

# Annotate
for i in s:
    ax.annotate('Plot Y%d' % s[i], [x[-1], yp[s[i]]], [a_posx[i], a_posy[i]],
                textcoords='axes fraction',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-', edgecolor=pp[s[i]].get_color(),
                                linestyle=als[s[i]]))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. I was guessing that I would need to use `text` instead of legend. But I did not know about `annotate`.